# How to have a file indented in gVim as soon as it is opened?

Tags: vim

I usually indent the file as soon as I open it using the command <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>. How do I use this command in *_vimrc* so that whenever I open a file, it'll be indented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try adding this line in your vimrc:

```
au BufReadPost * normal! gg=G
```

Answer (score 1):

With a package like [autoformat](https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat) it's easy to implement.

Put `autocmd BufReadPost :autoformat` in your .vimrc

You can also consider `BufWritePre`, which will indent while saving a file.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the package?

Comment: `BufEnter` will be triggered everytime you enter that buffer. I believe that it is pretty annoying, if you had this line in your vimrc..